# Check if message reply is a reply type message discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have the following basic python discord bot code:

```
@bot.command()
async def replyTest(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Reply to this message')
    def check(m):
        return m
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    print(msg)
```

Is there a way to return `m` only when `m` is a reply type message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply check if the message has a reference.

```py
def check(m):
    if m.reference is not None and not m.is_system:
         return True
    return False
```

Additionally, if you want to check if the reference points to a message:

```py
def check(m):
   if m.reference is not None:
        if m.reference.message_id == some_msg.id:
            return True
   return False
```

### References:

- [`message.reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.Message.reference)
- [`Reference.message_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.MessageReference.message_id)

Comment: Just as a note, this will include some other types of messages such as pin adds.

Comment: Fixed it by checking for it. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Would post an edit but there's too many. The second block will throw a syntax error. It should be `if m.reference.message_id == some_msg.id:`. You forgot the second `=` sign and the semicolon.