# How would I code my Discord.py bot to see if someone replies to a user(me)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Like the title says, I need to code my bot so that whenever a user replies to me(one of my posts) they get pinged and told not to. Something like this I presume...

`if`   `(message.author.mention)`   *replies to* (`My_ID`)

`await message.channel.send("Please don't ping me.")`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know if you're mentioned you can simply use [`message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.Message.mentions). Note that they aren't in any particular order, and that you can only check if you (or someone else) is in it or not.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send('hey you pinged me')
```

[image]

Otherwise, you would have to get the message that was replied (which is annoying).

```py
    reply_author = None if message.reference is None or client.get_channel(message.reference.channel_id) is None  \
        else (await client.get_channel(message.reference.channel_id).fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)).author
    if client.user in message.mentions and reply_author == client.user:
        await message.channel.send('you replied with ping')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can Check Some of These:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.Message.reference

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.MessageReference.message_id

Now, I found a Question which can solve the bit of your problem!

[Check if message reply is a reply type message discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956261/check-if-message-reply-is-a-reply-type-message-discord-py)

You can check this questions answer, and use that code in a Event! Not as a Command,

`@client.event`

Hope You are Trying to Understand Cause I am trying My Best!

Comment: I have got it kind of working now. How would say:
if (person is replying to a message posted by MY_ID)

I know it isn't message.author.id(because this just gets my id)