# How do I execute a command when someone is replying to one of my own messages Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need to say:
if ((message is a reply) AND (the message replied to is one of my previous messages))

Do thing()

I already know how to get the message if it is a reply, my only issue is I can't figure out how to say 'the message replied to is one of my previous messages'.
`message.author.id` gets my new messages id(Not the original post I am replying to), but doesn't work if I do

if (message="reply" AND message.author.id = my_ID)

This^ only does my command if the reply is done by me.
I want to get it so that anytime someone ELSE replies to one of my messages, the command is done

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I code my Discord.py bot to see if someone replies to a user(me)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341315/how-would-i-code-my-discord-py-bot-to-see-if-someone-replies-to-a-userme)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_message` event, check the message's `type`, and compare the message's reference's author id to the bot's. In this example I assume you have a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` object called `bot`, change it to suit your script.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.type == discord.MessageType.reply: # Checking if message is reply
        reference = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id) # Getting the message that was replied to

        if reference.author.id == bot.user.id: # Checking if the message was sent by the bot
            await message.reply("You replied to me!")
```

Comment: Hi, I keep getting an error now. `attribute error type object messagetype has no attribute reply`.  this is how I changed it:


```  if message.type == discord.MessageType.reply:
    reference = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)
    if reference.author.id == message.author.id == 515964084240515073:```

Comment: @Piepop101 Make sure you have v2.0 installed. Uninstall discord.py and install the latest version by doing `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`