# How do I get the message that a person is responding to?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, reply

I am coding a discord bot. When someone replies to a message with a specific command, the bot will create a poll to decide what to do with the replied-to message.

When the bot handles the command, how can it find the message (if any) that the command is replying to?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Check if message reply is a reply type message discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956261) - arguably, that task is a special case of this one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the code i have to check if a message is a reply is this:
`if message.type == discord.MessageType.reply:`
but in testing, that did not work, any suggestions

Comment: It's already explained in the link. In this question, you saw that you can use `message.reference`, when set to a message, to access what the message is replying to. The other question shows that, when the message *isn't* replying to anything, `message.reference` is set to `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the message with the command:

```py
original_message = (await client
    .get_channel(message.reference.channel_id)
    .fetch_message(message.reference.message_id))
```

This will throw a `discord.errors.NotFound` error if the channel or message cannot be found.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageReference